# How to add a tab in the color palette

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hello 
I am working in VB.Net 2.0 windows forms.

A color palette occurs on click of backcolor of any control. I want to add a new tab in this palette. In the new tab, I want to add the new colors as per the requirement.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cksxshce(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The actual dialog is a private class named ColorUI, nested inside the System.Drawing.Design.ColorEditor class.  That prevents you from altering it.

You'll need to create a complete replacement for this UITypeEditor derived class.  You can get implementation hints on getting this right by using Reflector.  Beware that you cannot override the [Editor] attribute on existing controls, your new version of the dialog will only be usable on your own custom controls.